# UPS Sync started from powershell script / web service

Tags: development, powershell, web-services

I have a web service that is kicked off from a workflow. The web service runs a powershell script that kicks off the User Profile Synchronization job.

The powershell script works perfectly if I run the script on the server. When I have the webservice kick off the script I get errors:

System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "StartSynchronization" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action.

```
Please try again.&quot; ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.

Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot complete this action.
```

Has anyone done anything like this before? Any idea why this doesn't work?

Here is my WebMethod in the web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public void RunUserProfileSync()
{
    RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
    runspace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(sychronizationScript());

    // Execute PowerShell script
    pipeline.Invoke();
}

    public string sychronizationScript()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader powerShellScript= new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\SynchronizationScript.ps1");
        var pSScript = powerShellScript.ReadToEnd();
        powerShellScript.Close();
        return pSScript;
    }
```

Here is the powershell script that I'm running:

```
#------- Get-SPServiceContext

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll'
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell"

function Get-SPServiceContext([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication]$profileApp)
{
    if($profileApp -eq $null)
    {
        #----- Get first User Profile Service Application
        $profileApp = @(Get-SPServiceApplication | ? { $_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application" })[0]
    }  
return [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext(
        $profileApp.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup, 
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier]::Default) 
}

$serviceContext= Get-SPServiceContext
$configManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($serviceContext)
if($configManager.IsSynchronizationRunning() -eq $false)
{
$configManager.StartSynchronization($true) 
Write-Host "Started Synchronizing"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Already Synchronizing"
}
```

any help would be appreciated!